# How to write multi query in PHP using database extension PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to write this MYSQL query

```
SET @val := 0;
SELECT `my_table`.* FROM `my_table` HAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0;
```

inside `PHP` code that using database extention `PDO`!

I've seen that `mysqli` have `mysqli_multi_query()` but i do not know does `PDO` support multi queries by some how?!

I've try this

```
<?PHP
// i'm connected to db

    $sql = "SET @val := 0;";
    $sql .= "SELECT `my_table`.* FROM `my_table` HAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0;";
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    <?PHP foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

But did not works!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in \path\test.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in \path\test.php on line 25
```

and line 25 is : `<?PHP foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){ ?>` looks like it not passing the query! so any idea

Comment: you have a typo in` "SELECT table.* FROM tableHAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0;";`   you should add  a space between `tableHaving` ...`table Having`

Comment: @scaisEdge OH YEA, sorry that was a typo error when i was writing the post but i've updated it now .. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is working fine. Your issue is that there are two result sets returned by `$db->query($sql)`: the first for the `SET @val := 0` and the second for your actual `SELECT` query. When you loop on the result of `$db->query()` you are getting the first result set i.e. the results from `SET @val := 0` which is causing a crash. What you need to do is switch to the next result set, which will require rewriting your code slightly. Change:

```
<?PHP foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){ ?>
```

to:

```
<?php
$result = $db->query($sql);
$result->nextRowset();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
?>
```

Comment: that was my question is about, thank you a lot .. you've given me a flash light for the first time knowing about nextRowset().

Answer (score 1):

should work   multiquery is supported  by PDO so  you should check for typo in your code eg: add space beetween clause (`table HAVING` and not `tableHAVING` )  and use backticks for resevred  word  eg:

```
$sql = "SET @val := 0;";
$sql .= "SELECT `table`.* FROM `table` HAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0;";
```

Comment: thank you and i've upaded the question and added the error that appears to me when using that way.

Answer (score 1):

First your script is vulnerable to XSS Attack. I do not see where you are escaping the outputted variables with **htmlentities or htmlspecialchars()** functions.

This code will do the trick for you. I have tested it and it works.

create a table name called **table1** with following field
**id** and
**name**

```
create table table1(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(100));
```

insert values into it and use the code below but remember to change database connection propertise

```
 <?php

    //connect to db



    $db = new PDO (
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_db;charset=utf8', 
        'root', // username

        '' // password
    );


    $result = $db->prepare("SET @val := 0");
    $result->execute(array());



    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT `table1`.* FROM `table1` HAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0");
    $result->execute(array());


    while ($row = $result->fetch()) 
    {

    //prevent xss Attack using htmlentities
    $id = htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $name = htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    //}



    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you for caring about term of `security comes first` but actually I'm someone beleives in conspiracy theory so i'm using different layers of security on real working code, but this one was just an model for the core problem which is differences than mysqli_multi_query() as you might write all queries as set then execute all of them once... but anyway i might stick with your answer as it seems to be the only way .. thank you again for your clear and straight forward answer

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question on stack overflow [PHP & MySQL: How can I use "SET @rank=0;" in $query=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100902/php-mysql-how-can-i-use-set-rank-0-in-query)

or try this

```
SELECT `my_table`.* FROM `my_table` ,(SELECT @val:=0) r HAVING (@val := @val + 1) > 0;
```